# Why is my header not being injected into my javadoc by maven?

Tags: maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I'm trying to inject Google Analytics tracking into my javadocs, but it's not working.

I have the following in my POM file:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <!-- GA Tracking code -->
            <header>
                <![CDATA[
                    <script>
                      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
                      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

                      ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-1', 'auto');
                      ga('send', 'pageview');

                    </script>
                ]]>
            </header>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Running `mvn javadoc:aggregate` builds my Javadocs without throwing an error, but my header is nowhere to be found.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I don't see a defect around it, but I think the injection of the property with the value from the `pom.xml` under `<header>` does not happen properly for this property.</strike>

See my other answer for the actual solution.

You can try this instead:

> mvn javadoc:aggregate -Dheader="(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-1', 'auto');ga('send', 'pageview');"

Ugly I know, but not sure if there's a way to make it work unless the underlying problem is fixed.

<strike>On the other hand, you could try a particular older version of the `maven-javadoc-plugin` to see if it works with that. Or raise a bug [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAVADOC), so they can get this resolved.</strike>

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that version tomorrow and accept if it works

Answer (score 1):

Ok - I see what you're doing differently.

While my other answer provided a workaround, it didn't explain what the problem really was correctly. But that answer lead me to the right one, so thought I'll leave it undeleted.

While your `POM` configuration looks correct, what you should really have run is

`mvn site`

and not any specific goal of any specific plugin configured in the `<reporting>` section. Reading the  [vs.  section](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_reporting_Tag_VS_build_Tag), I think it should have worked as such though, but doesn't seem to! It looks like the `<configuration>` of a reporting plugin is completely ignored when a specific reporting goal is run, when it should really have attempted to check for presence of the property once.

In any case, this is how `Maven` behaves - so it's not a bug with any specific plugin.

> **mvn site**
>
> It uses only the parameters defined in the  element of each reporting Plugin specified in the `<reporting>` element, i.e.
>   site always ignores the parameters defined in the 
>   element of each plugin specified in `<build>`.
>
> **mvn aplugin:areportgoal**
>
> It uses firstly the parameters defined in the
>    element of each reporting Plugin specified in the
>    element; if a parameter is not found, it will look up to a
>   parameter defined in the `<configuration>` element of each plugin
>   specified in `<build>`.

Comment: I read that too... the `mvn aplugin:areportgoal` states : "It uses firstly the parameters defined in the element of each reporting Plugin specified in the element". I read this as meaning that it *will* look in `<reporting>`.

Comment: "I read this as meaning that it will look in `<reporting>`" - so did I. Hence the uncertainty in my answer. It should really have read the `<header>` even when you ran a specific goal, but apparently it didn't - so it's either a bug with the `Maven` code or the documentation.

Comment: Actually, it seems like the `header` option just doesn't work at all... trying it from the CLI with just a simple string fails to inject anything.

Comment: Really? This did work for me: 

`mvn javadoc:aggregate -Dheader=headerStringAtTheTopRightOfThePage`. You should see the string at the top right corner of every javadoc page with this.

Comment: What version of the maven-javadoc-plugin are you using? Maybe there's a bug in the latest version.

Comment: I'm an idiot... see my answer... sorry for wasting your time :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is embarrassing.

The content was being inserted all along. The issue was that I was using IntelliJ's  find function to see if the header injection was working.

Unfortunately, the `target` directory is excluded from the search index, so those files weren't being searched (even though the folder was explicitly selected).

The code in the question works just fine.